# gradle build encoding Korean alphabet

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is it possible to build a folder in Korean alphabet?
I used to this way : [compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
The build is succeed but in build jar file not has class files.

Comment: You mean to create directory whose name is Korean in SDcard?

Comment: yes.. directory name is Korean

Comment: like this : src/테스트, src/리소스

Comment: @SilentKnight do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't create any directories packages or files whose names are not English. Because **no any non-English programming languages** are created or popular. English is the main stream programming language. **Non-English programming languages are not universal language and has little efficiency**. Maybe after you Korean invent a Korean programming language, this can be done. Computer Science origins and prospers in UK/USA. And any information of Computer is English. All the world have to follow their rules. I am sorry about that.
BTW, you can create any directories or files with name in any language in SDCard.

PS:Here is details of internal or external storage, have a check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363554/access-external-storage-in-file-chooser#29381424)
And I hope this will help you to understand your questions.